# Dismiss multiple DialogFragment at the same time

Tags: android

I have a Fragment that launches a DialogFragment which also launches another DialogFragment.

Fragment1 -> DialogFragment2 -> Dialogfragment3

In Dialogfragment3 I have a button that when clicked should bring the user back to Fragment1.

I tried to call `dismiss()` in Dialogfragment3 and when the user return back to Dialogfragment2 call `dismiss()` again, but the result is not great, user still sees DialogFragment2 briefly before they see Fragment1.

What's the recommended way to deal with my situation?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
What's the recommended way to deal with my situation?
```

I would dismiss `DialogFragment2` before showing `Dialogfragment3`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you show `DialogFragment` by `childFragmentManager` of `Fragment1` Try this inside your `Dialogfragment3` (Kotlin)

```
        requireParentFragment().childFragmentManager.fragments.forEach {
            if (it is DialogFragment) {
                it.dismiss()
            }
        }
```